# Is there a way to implement knitr chunk and knit options as a project-wide environment or profile for R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, reproducible-research

I've grown tired of repeating the beginning of R Markdown documents over and over again to set up my preferences for knitting and chunk options. An example:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = FALSE, message = FALSE,
                  warning = FALSE, fig.align = 'center')
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = 'DATA/PATH'))
```
````

If you use this chunk to begin the majority of you `.Rmd` files, can you embed this into the `.Renviron` or `.RProfile` for an R Project? I know you can load libraries via your `.RProfile`, and I know `knitr::opts_knit$set` also has some sort of integration with `options(knitr.package.foo)` in your `.RProfile`, but I have been unsuccessful in getting the `options()` route to work, and it only accounts for the knitting options, excluding the chunk options. It feels like there should be an easier way to reproduce this, but I can't find any resources exploring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to develop a small package that includes it following the steps outlined here: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rmarkdown_templates.html

Here's an example: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles

As it's bad practice to link-only, here are the steps:

1. Create a package
2. Create the folder: inst/rmarkdown/templates/my_template
3. Inside of this folder create a file called `template.yaml` and
   `skeleton/skeleton.Rmd`
4. Build and install the package and the templates should show up.

- `template.yaml` will contain the topmatter YAML
- `skeleton/skeleton.Rmd` will contain your default Rmd.

Alternative:

Edit the default files for your Rstudio installation. Depending on your platform they are in something like `resources/r_markdown_v2.Rmd` folder of your Rstudio install. But, this will get wiped out anytime you update RStudio.